# Black screen instead of login screen

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I just installed linux mint 19.3 on my ASUS Gl703-GE, and something seems to be wrong with the login screen of the os

I am able to type my password and press enter to get into the desktop, where everything functions normally(to my knowledge, i haven't found any bugs yet). This doesn't pose as much of a threat right now, but i may need to add more users in the future, and this issue will make it hard to switch users, so can someone please help me fix this?

EDIT :

I have tried reinstalling the os twice, the problem persists

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially be a driver issue - once you are logged in try updating the graphics card drivers. Based on a Google this looks to be a laptop with a Nvidia graphics card, so perhaps you'll need to install the Nvidia drivers to have some success here.

Failing that you could also try changing the login window manager to something else to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No, that isn't the problem. I have installed the drivers using sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall . And am also using the nvidia cuda library for data science, but the problem still persists. I have also tried using older drivers for my card, but it still doesn't fix the issue